# Handlbars JS : evaluating expression with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have object as follows

```
myObject = {
     id:1234,
     name_1234:"abc"
}
```

using the handlebars JS i am trying to evaluate the expression with dynamic keys in place, for example the id is generated dynamically so the keys will change dynamically

therefore the expression below

```
{{"myObject.name_"+myObject.id}}
```

should return the output "abc".

Is something like this achievable in handlebars JS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars will not allow you to concatenate strings within a template using the `+` operator. You will need to create a Helper to do that. Once you have that, you can combine it with the [lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) using a [subexpression](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions) to perform the lookup:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function (...args) {
    return args.slice(0, -1).join('');
});

{{lookup myObject (concat "name_" myObject.id)}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lchd0g1o/) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties through brackets like you can access an array value by index. Try this:

```
{{myObject["name_" + myObject.id]}}
```